# Problema ao enviar Arquivo com FormData no Angular 11

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

Estou tentando enviar um arquivo usando FormData mas na hora da requisição o arquivo desaparece no payload
O que acontece é que pelo swagger o arquivo é enviado normalmente
eu analisei o payload dele e vi que aparece um binário na request que não aparece no meu
Eu preciso Guardar o arquivo em uma variável porque preciso de uma resposta de outra requisição pra fazer a request do arquivo, aqui eu fiz com o Id '22811' só pra fim de testes.

Esse é o html

```
    <div class="anexo" [formGroup]="clientForm">
      <input mat-input  type="file" formControlName="anexo" required (change)="uploadArquivo($event)">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" color="primary" (click)="iniciaTeste()" >
      SALVAR
    </button>
```

Essa é  a minha função no Typescript

```
  uploadArquivo(event) {

  this.fileAnexo = event.target.files[0];

  this.formDataAnexo.append('ArquivosAnexo', this.fileAnexo);

  }

  iniciarUpload(codparc: string, cara: FormData){
    this.clienteService.apiClientePostAnexo(codparc, cara).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        if(response){
        this.toastr.success('Arquivo Anexo enviado com sucesso!', response.message);
        }else{
          this.toastr.error('Erro ao enviar arquivo de Anexo!', response.message);
        }
      }
    );

  }

  iniciaTeste(){
    this.iniciarUpload((22811).toString(),this.formDataAnexo);
  }
```

Esse é o serviço

```
public apiClientePostAnexo(
codparc: string,
file: FormData
){
return this.http.post(
  environment.apiUrl +
  backend.CLIENTE_POST_ANEXO +
  `codParc=${codparc}`,  file,
  this.httpOptionsAnexo
);
```

}

Esse é o meu payload
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o payload do Swagger
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é o jeito que o swagger envia o arquivo para o endpoint
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Consegui achar a solução
apenas trocando o header resolve o envio

substituí

```
Content-Type
```

por

```
Content-disposition
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).